# Encrypted hard drive with messed up Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, encryption, truecrypt

I decided I wanted to modify `authui.dll` in System32. I followed the guide and opened it in Resource Hacker, modifying a few lines and then saving the new version to my desktop.

My goal was to remove the Ease Of Access Center button, the Windows 7 logo, and the picture frame of an account on the login/lock screen of Windows 7.

I opened up System32 in Windows Explorer and renamed `authui.dll` to `authui_backup.dll`. I'm an idiot for this because apparently that is an essential file for User Account Control to work, and thus I couldn't move in the modified version from my desktop because it required authentication. No biggie, I thought, because I made a Restore Point before I had changed anything.

I restarted my computer and when it booted to a black screen I realized I messed up. I proceeded to shut it back down, then I fooled it into thinking it didn't start correctly by turning it off while it was still booting. I turned it back on and launched Startup Repair, only to panic after realizing that it can't read my restore points because I encrypted my hard drive with TrueCrypt 7.1a (Whole drive, not Windows only.) So I tried a few things to try and fix this without Factory Restoring but to no avail. I decided eventually that I had to do it.

Then the second kick happened. I had set up TrueCrypt to have that whole no text on screen thing except for a custom error message. I typed my password and pressed enter only to see nothing happening. I typed it again, but mid-way my computer beeped at me through its speakers. Now I can't even shut it off mid-boot to run Startup Repair to Factory Restore!

I don't know what to do except make a bootable Windows 7 flash drive and install TrueCrypt on that, then somehow decrypt the hard drive while running on the flash drive. I haven't done that so far as I don't have access to another computer, but I don't even care about my files at this point.

It won't take that long to re-setup everything and all my sensitive data is backed up elsewhere. All I want is to be able to Factory Restore it, wipe the encryption off, fresh Windows install, new accounts and files. And before anyone says it, yes I've thought about a hard drive enclosure and I'm considering it. As long as I can decrypt my hard drive so it'll run Windows without error. And I don't have any install disc, nor can I even use one. My CD-ROM tray is broken.

**Does anyone have any idea of what I can do to salvage my computer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought a USB external DVD burner/writer, bought recovery media and a key, then installed a fresh new Windows and spent a little while hunting down the drivers I needed via bootable flash drive. (I had no internet on Windows because of lack of drivers.)